# How does Angular Component be rendered in HTML?Or in what form does angular component template exist in dom?

Tags: css, angular, web, google-chrome-devtools, web-component

I'm new to angular, and WEB to be honest.Now I am doing some experiments with angular and Chrome dev tools.I created a quite simple component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'fa-input',
  templateUrl: './fa-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fa-input.component.css']
})
```

whose template is just a input wrapped in div

```
<div>
  <input>
</div>
```

In chrome element inspector, I saw
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECvl7.png)
Then I got confused with some basic concepts.Are app-root and fa-input real elements in the html? If so, are they so-called custom elements? If angular components are represented as custom elements, why there is another concept called Angular elements? And do they have relationship with
a concept called web components? Are they rendered in dom as shadow dom? Are all custom elements rendered in the form of shadow dom?
I also tried to add css style to the template.

```
:host {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

In chrome dev tools I saw
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFzhU.png)
It seems :host get the component shadow root(does it?).But the style didn't apply.I can't see the border as the css described.Can someone explain how angular components be attached to html and rendered in dom? How can I use chrome dev tools more effectivly? Many many thanks!

Comment: You are trying to (learn to) ride a uni-cycle and learning to juggle at the same time. If you have to make a choice learn standard Web Components and forget about Angular.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.But I have to be familiar with angular very soon because of a project from job. I just had very limited experience with web,so I want to make these concepts clear. Can you help me?